# What is the proper way to zoom in and out using orthographic projection?

Tags: c++, math, matrix, glm-math

I have a view matrix:

```
    float left = -(float)viewPortWidth / 240, right = (float)viewPortWidth / 240, down = -(float)viewPortHeight / 240, up = (float)viewPortHeight / 240;
    viewMatrix = glm::ortho(left, right, down, up, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```

I am dividing by 240 to be able to show 16:9 units when it is full screen. Here is how it looks like:
[image]

I have a class `Camera2D` and I want to give it a size capability like Unity or at least achieve something similar. Before, I was using the transformation matrix of the game object attached to the camera and multiplying it by `viewMatrix`, but that leads to many unwanted effects if I make game object a child of the camera. I tried adding the number of extra vertical and horizontal unites I want to `left, right, down, up` but it leads to stretching effects.

I want to be able to have a zoom feature where 1 would add one vertical or horizontal unit. How can I do this?

Update 1:
I tried this:

```
    float left = -(float)(viewPortWidth + 240) / 240, right = (float)(viewPortWidth + 240) / 240, down = -(float)(viewPortHeight + 240) / 240, up = (float)(viewPortHeight + 240) / 240;
    viewMatrix = glm::ortho(left, right, down, up, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```

But it still leads to stretching effects.

Comment: The left/right/down/up *are* the size of the camera. Are you trying to figure out how to calculate them?

Comment: I know they are the size of the camera. Those values are correct. However, I want to be able to resize the camera by ```n``` units. If is I want to resize the camera to show exactly one more unit, what mathematical calculations would I have to do?

Comment: [tag:glm] != [tag:glm-math]

Comment: If you make it show one more unit in the X and one more unit in the Y, then you change the ratio of X to Y (unless it was square already). That's just how it works. You can't add 1 unit to X and also add 1 unit to Y and also keep the aspect ratio at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try dividing all the parameters.

```
float zoom = 16.0f / 14.0f; // 114% zoom in  

float left = -(float)viewPortWidth / 240, right = (float)viewPortWidth / 240, down = -(float)viewPortHeight / 240, up = (float)viewPortHeight / 240;

viewMatrix = glm::ortho(left / zoom, right / zoom, down / zoom, up / zoom, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```

#### Another approach

Or otherwise, if you'd like to  control zoom level by specifying the number of units to be shown directly, try:

```
float n = 14.0f * unit_size; // Align 14 units horizontally in the screen.

const float aspectRatio = (float)viewPortWidth / viewPortHeight;
float left = -n * 0.5f, right = n * 0.5f, down = -n * 0.5f / aspectRatio, up = n * 0.5f / aspectRatio;

viewMatrix = glm::ortho(left, right, down, up, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Comment: It works. (114% zoom in) == (16.0f / 14.0f) with 16 being default units and 14 being the number of units to be show on the screen when the window is maximized. I appreciate your answer. In the meantime, I implemented a temporary solution, but I am going to change everything to the math you provided. Thank you!

Comment: Practically, it might be better to make viewable-range independent of viewport size (raw-dimensions). So, try also `another approach` I newly appended to the answer above, if you like. thank you.